# Is there a tangible benefit to using wrapper requests over plain messages in grpc service calls?

Tags: grpc

Lets say we have a message containing ID of some record in the database

```
message Record {
    uint64 id = 1;
}
```

We also have an rpc call that returns all of the rows from table DATA that said record is mentioned in.

```
rpc GetDataForRecord(Record) returns (Data) {}
```

If we, for example, wrap Record in

```
RqData{
    Record id = 1;
}
```

then once we need to only return, for example, "active" data, we won't need to make

```
GetActiveDataForRecord
```

instead we could extend RqData as:

```
RqData{
    Record id = 1;
    bool use_active = 2;
}
```

and use

```
rpc GetDataForRecord(RqData) returns (Data) {}
```

and clients that know of this new functionality will be able to call it, while older clients will just use it as it was passing only Record part within the Rq wrapper, without specifying active or not.

**Here's the question:** is there really a reason to use this kind of wrapping of everything into a separate request, or am I overthinking things and just passing plain structures will do?

I am kinda trying to think about the future, but not sure if I am not overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

In general, making a method-specific request and response is a Good Thing™ and is encouraged. For a `Foo` method you'd have `FooRequest` and `FooResponse`. Having specialized messages for the method allows you to add new "arguments," as you mentioned.

But for some cases it turns out fine to break the pattern and avoid the wrapping; it's a judgement call. Although you're asking from a different perspective, you may be interested in this [answer about related methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45944673/4690866).